# Install Swift4.1 on ubuntu16.04 and CFStringEncodings not work

Tags: swift, ubuntu-16.04, core-foundation

I install Swift4.1 on ubuntu16.04.

After finishing install, I run swift build found some error like

`Compile Swift Module 'PerfectTemplate' (15 sources)
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/MinuteRepeat.swift:368:13: warning: variable 'idxx' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
        var idxx = phoneModels[idx].idx!
        ~~~ ^
        let
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:44:161: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:115:161: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:137:25: error: use of unresolved identifier 'arc4random_uniform'
        let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:258:161: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:314:161: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:188:165: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                    if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
/home/ubuntu/PttTrader/Sources/PTTManager + Extension.swift:229:165: error: type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'
                    if let response = String(data: messageMenuData , encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.big5.rawValue)))) {
                                                                                                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~
error: terminated(1): /swift-4.1/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /home/ubuntu/PttTrader/.build/debug.yaml main output:`

It says ‘type 'CFStringEncodings' (aka 'Int') has no member 'big5'' but when I run the same code in my local xcode it is fine.

Can someone can tell me how to fix it? or some way to replace the 'CFStringEncodings' function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please give more details about the context. How did you install? The error message should go into the text, not in an image. This will make it easier to comprehend your problem.

Comment: I install by this link https://gist.github.com/serhii-londar/28e3995886a47c2369b81b0b1dccb106

Comment: And I write the error image instead of context. Thanks for your remind!